# WPF: Need help in adding UserControl in DataGrid using the DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate

Tags: wpf, user-controls, wpfdatagrid

I have a WPF UserControl. I want to add that user control in first column of every row in the `DataGrid`. I have used `DataTemplate` to achieve this. I add a new row when user hits ENTER key in the last row of the DataGrid. `Organisation:OrganisationPicker` is the UserControl below.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="250" Header="{x:Static resx:Resources.Organisation}" x:Name="OrgPickerColumn" CellStyle="{StaticResource SingleClickEditing}">                                
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" Name="column1"></ColumnDefinition>
          <!--<ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*"></ColumnDefinition>-->
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Organisation:OrganisationPicker Width="240"
                                         HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2,2,2,2"
                                         Name="orgPicker"
                                         VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                         Grid.Column="0"
                                         IsValidSearch="{Binding OrganisationError,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,ValidatesOnDataErrors=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true,NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" 
                                         SelectedOrganisationalUnit="{Binding Path=ReqOrganisationId,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,ValidatesOnDataErrors=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true,NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"
                                         Foreground="{DynamicResource ContentForeground}" FontFamily="{DynamicResource DefaultFontFamily}" FontSize="{DynamicResource NormalFontSize}">
        </Organisation:OrganisationPicker>                                           
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

User control gets added but when new row is entered, **constructor of the user control is called as many times as number of rows in the grid** and obviously I lose the state of the user control instances that are in already present rows.

e.g. If new row thats being added is the 5th row in grid, then constructor is called 5 times!

**Why does it happen? How can I prevent it to happen?**

Comment: My best guess is the entire DataGrid is being redrawn when a new item is added. Perhaps you can show us the code where you add a new item? And WPF purposely unloads controls that aren't needed, so if a property isn't bound to anything then it will lose it's value. It's good practice to bind your selections to something, because even something like minimizing your application and restoring it will redraw (and reset) unbound controls.

Comment: @Rachel: This is not the case. Grid has 4 other columns which retain their data/state without any problem. I am sorry but its hard to post code here because it's very complex and huge in size. I would be grateful if you could guide me further. If code is absolutely necessary, I'll try to pull out smaller chunks here.

Comment: Can you show the piece of code that gets executed when you press Enter?

Comment: Show the relevant code for the DataGrid and bindings. (Scrub any visual information, such as Margin, Width, alignments, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that view model was not written correctly. The collection which is bound to the grid was reinitialized everytime new row is added. So I fixed the view model and it worked.

Thanks to all for contributing your comments here.

I am closing this question because solution was too local and it was impossible to identify problem on online forum.

Answer (score 0):

You say you loose the state for your control.

I think you must store the relevant data for your control at the view model behind your ui/control (per binding etc.).

Your control/column is only a presenter for your data.

I don't know how exactly the grid works, but I think by the virtualization in the `Grid`, your control will be generated as often as it takes the control.

Hope this helps.